# rsync backup does not include /boot and /home

Tags: rsync

I'm trying to backup my system using rsync. I've read some tutorials and finally write my command:

```
rsync -aAxv --del --ignore-errors --force \
      --exclude={"/home/*/.thumbnails/*",\
                 "/home/*/.cache/mozilla/*",\
                 "/home/*/.cache/chromium/*",\
                 "/home/*/.local/share/Trash/*",\
                 "/home/*/.gvfs",\
                 "/home/shirain/Bureau/",\
                 "/dev/*",\
                 "/proc/*",\
                 "/sys/*",\
                 "/tmp/*",\
                 "/run/*",\
                 "/mnt/*",\
                 "/media/*",\
                 "/lost+found"} \
      --stats \
      --filter "- .thumbnails/" \
      --filter "- .Trash/" \
      --filter "- *.tmp" \
      --filter "- lost+found/" \
      --filter "- .cache/" \
      --filter "- .beagle/" \
      / /run/media/shirain/SSD/backup_root_rsync
```

But, `rsync` exclude doesn't copy anything from the folders `/home` and `/boot`. I was thinking it was just a strange thing when you want to backup `/`, so I've done another command to backup `/boot` and `/home`.

But, in `/home`, as you can see, I don't want `/home/shirain/Bureau/` and other specific folders, but `rsync` copies them.

So my question is, what's the option to say to `rsync` to copy `/home` and not the the folders I've chosen?

```
"/home/*/.thumbnails/*","/home/*/.cache/mozilla/*","/home/*/.cache/chromium/*","/home/*/.local/share/Trash/*","/home/*/.gvfs","/home/shirain/Bureau/")
```

and: `/boot`, in one command.

I'm on manjaro linux 16.06.

Comment: use a separate `--exclude` for each pattern.

Comment: I've do this but nothing change (and on arch linux wiki is said that you can you {} with bash). But Ipor Sircer's answer works so i definitly think it's not this.

Answer (score 2):

I think your `/boot` and `/home` is on a different partition.
Remove `-x` parameter, which means *don't cross filesystem boundaries*

Comment: Thank you, it had worked well. But, if i have to restore the system, is it a possible source of problems because unknow or bad "architectures" of the different partitions?

Comment: x64 is compatible with i386 + x64.
i386 compatible with itself.
and i don't use devices with arm*, so ask somebody else of arm compatibility.